# Is there any posssible ways to take scheduled postgresql daily backup and push it into AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I need to take backup of postgresql db in every day and push it into S3 bucket. is there any solution for that?

i am using ubuntu 16.04 and postgresql version is 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [django-dbbackup](https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup) package is probably your easiest option.
[It supports backups to S3](https://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/storage.html#amazon-s3).

You can then run a daily cron job using [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) as instructed [here](https://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integration.html?highlight=cron#django-cron).